# WordPress: override multiple css files in child theme in the proper order

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

How can I enqueue more css files from the parent theme in the child theme and in which order?

Note: the previous method was to import the parent theme stylesheet using `@import`, but this is no longer best practice, because it uploads the stylesheet twice.

The correct method of enqueuing the parent theme stylesheet is to add a `wp_enqueue_scripts` action and use `wp_enqueue_style()` in the child theme's *functions.php*.

So, this is the correct PHP code to use:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
```

But this uploads only *style.css* and all themes have multiple css files, so how can I enqueue all of them? And how can I keep the proper order of uploading files?

For example, how can I enqueue the file *main.css* from the path *theme_parent_directory/css/main.css* in addition to *style.css*?

I hope that my English is clear. :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The solution is, simply, to use more specific rules in your style.css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles',999 );
  function theme_enqueue_styles() {
     wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
     wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css' );
     wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
      array( $parent_style )
     );
}

?>
```

Comment: So, generally, one has to copy `wp_enqueue_style` calls from parent *functions.php*? Why is that, given that parent's *functions.php* are run just after child's *functions.php*?